# django-pytest ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, django, pytest, pytest-django

I'm running django==4.0.7 and python==3.10 and django-pytest==0.2.0.

When I run my app using the command `python manage.py runserver` it works fine.

But when I run the command `pytest` I get module not found error.

in the settings.py file I've imported the following:

```
from corsheaders.defaults import default_headers
```

so when i run `pytest` i get the following error.

```
from corsheaders.defaults import default_headers
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'corsheaders'
```

Whereas it is corsheaders is already installed django-cors-headers==3.13.0.

my pytest.ini

```
[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = app.settings
python_files = tests.py test_*.py *_tests.py
```

What is going wrong? How could I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

use this command to check whether corsheaders are installed or not

```
pip freeze
```

if there is no corsheaders then it means it is not installed.
Either activate your virtual environment if created any or just install tha package directly into your system using command:-

```
pip install django-cors-headers
```